# How Oracle Adf Query Works internally?

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-apps

I am new to ADF applications and I have a requirement to customize ADF query. But I'm not sure how to customize ADF Query and also can you explian detail how ADF Query works internally

Comment: What version of ADF? https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-vo-queries.htm#ADFFD236

Comment: How do I get Adf version?

Comment: Tell us what JDeveloper version you are using. Help > About

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDeveloper 11g..                                                                            Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.7.0                                                                  Build JDEVADF_11.1.1.7.0_GENERIC_130226.1400.6493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What customization? Are you trying to grab the query event and replace/extend/override it? For more in-depth on how the internals of ADF works, take a look at this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/oracle-adf-real-world-developer%E2%80%99s-guide).

Comment: Could you please provide the URL,the above url is not working

Comment: fixed, not sure what happened.